# Whatwg Fetch fails when json parsing an empty response, how can I prevent it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch-api

I'm using the Fetch API both in the frontend and on the backend (NodeJS), a problem that I've been facing a lot happens when parsing the response as json.

`response.json()` will return a promise so I don't know beforehand what the body of the response is, and when the body is empty the JSON parsing will fail with the error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

So my question is, how to prevent parsing the response when its empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Once you have the `Response` object, inspect the headers and see what `Content-Length` says. Based on that you can know whether or not there is something to parse. But also, it seems bogus for the server to return an `application/json` resource that is empty, as that is not JSON.

Comment: Yes, I found that to work most of the times, unfortunately sometimes the back end doesn't implement that header, so I need to find a way to do it without that header too.

Comment: An alternative is to use `text()` and `JSON.parse()` the result of that. That has the downside of allocating more memory than needed, but if the responses are small that might be okay.

Comment: I'm checking if `response.status === 204` (the status code for `No-Content`) and then skipping `response.json()` in that case.

Comment: Although it is contrary to @Anne 's advice, I had the unique experience in .NET. If you returned an `Ok()` with no result added, you would get 'content-length: 0' in the response. That was helpful enough for me to determine whether I should use `.json()`, although I now learned, why should not use an Ok() response with a blank result: it's impromper.

Comment: It's fine to have an ok status response that's blank. 204 is all about that. It just shouldn't advertise itself as JSON. I.e., what you want to branch on is the `Content-Type` header or potentially the status code if the server uses 204 to indicate no response.

Answer (score 16):

Since `response.json()` returns a Promise, You can handle the error with `catch` and return a dummy data object.

```
fetch('url').then(response => { 
  return response.json().catch(err => {
    console.error(`'${err}' happened, but no big deal!`);
    return {};
  });
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data); 
});
```

### Update

As mentioned below, if you try to read `response` twice, you'll get an error: `TypeError: Already Read`.

As a workaround, it you can `clone` the original response and call `json` on the cloned object.

```
fetch('url').then(response => {
  const responseCopy = response.clone();
  return responseCopy.json().catch(_ => response.text());
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to keep a single catch block for all my promises. What I really need is a way to know when not to parse.

Comment: Why? This `catch` block will only handle errors thrown by JSON parser.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that there seems to be no way to get the original body back if JSON parsing fails (due to an empty body or invalid JSON) then you can't get back the original body (`TypeError: Already Read`).  If you instead use `.text()` and `JSON.parse()` you're parsing the JSON in the main thread, which is also undesirable.

Comment: Have you tried to parse the response body in a web worker?

Comment: This solved it for me, was having an issue in react-native

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't handle error with try catch

```
try {
    body = JSON.parse(body)
} catch (err) {

}
```

Comment: Hi there, because the `response.json()` method returns a promise, you need to do something like:
`response.json().then((data) => //data is now parsed);`

Comment: You can use `.text` to get the content and then parse it, e.g. `response.text().then(data => { let body; try { body = JSON.parse(data); } catch (e) { /* do stuff */ } });`

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, just check response body type like below:

```
var contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
        if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1) {
            return response.json();
        }else{
            //if response is not json and mostly empty
            return({})
        }
```

it return empty object if response was null

Comment: The question was about the case when content-type IS application/json, but the content is empty. This does NOT resolve the original question.