# Fetch API: Can 'await res.json()' fail after a completed request?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

A fetch API request will only fail if there is a network or server error. So for example, if I execute the following code, assuming it went through the `try` block without an error, I will have a valid populated `res`.

```
try {
    const res = await fetch('/createurl', { 
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'testData',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })

    if (res.ok) {
        alert('Resource created!')
    } else {
        alert('Error creating resource!')
    }

    flashResponseToUser(res)
} catch(e) {
    alert('A server or network error occurred during the request!')
}
```

I am handling `res` to show the users the necessary `error` or `success` message using the `flashResponseToUser(res)` function. Since `res.json()` returns a `Promise`, `flashResponseToUser` has to be an async function.

```
const flashResponseToUser = async(res) => {
    const jsonRes = await res.json() // Get data from response
    console.log(jsonRes)
}
```

I want to know:

1. Why does `res.json()` return a `Promise` since at this point the response has already been received by the client?
2. Under what conditions would the `Promise` returned by `res.json()` fail?
3. Does the code within `flashResponseToUser(res)` also need to be wrapped within a `try-catch` block since I am using `res.json()`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body this will be able help you with those questions.

Comment: @Siege21x I did read that but it still doesn't explain why res.json() returns a Promise instead of returned data directly. Also doesn't tell us under what conditions res.json() fails.

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise) for first question. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280029/whatwg-fetch-fails-when-json-parsing-an-empty-response-how-can-i-prevent-it) for second question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why does res.json() return a Promise since at this point the response has already been received by the client?

`fetch` returns a Response object. This indicates that the *headers* of the response have been received, but does not necessarily mean that the whole response has been received - imagine, for example, when you load a huge page. It's not *exactly* the same thing, but you'll receive the headers and the browser will start to load the response even though there's still more to download. The Response object provides the headers and a way to handle still-incoming data.

> Under what conditions would the Promise returned by res.json() fail?

It might fail if the response wasn't in proper JSON format. For example, if the plain text of the response was `Internal Server Error`, which isn't JSON. Here's an example:

```js
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('data:,Internal%20Server%20Error');
  console.log('got response');
  try {
    await response.json();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('error:', e.message);
  }
})();
```

> Does the code within flashResponseToUser(res) also need to be wrapped within a try-catch block since I am using res.json()?

If you wanted to be perfectly safe, yes. But, in most situations, it's easiest just to catch in *one place*, where you can handle the error. Instead of handling possible errors at every step of the process, you might handle the error just once, in the consumer, eg:

```
const getInfo = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('/createurl', { 
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'testData',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(res.status);
  }
  return res.json();
};
getInfo()
  .then(flashResponseToUser)
  .catch(() => {
    alert('A server or network error occurred during the request!')
  })
```

(assuming that `flashResponseToUser` will never throw, if provided with an expected object. If `flashResponseToUser` might throw anyway, you can separate out the `.catch`es to distinguish network errors from other runtime errors)

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation. Will mark this as the answer as soon as I can!

Comment: JSON format failure happens more often than one would think. Sometimes your framework will return an error page that is HTML instead of json. Sometimes your reverse proxy (nginx or apache front-end) will return an error page that is HTML instead of json. Sometimes your office or ISP caching server will return an error page that is HTML instead of json. You don't necessarily have control of all conditions

Comment: Oh, don't forget that public Wifi will sometimes hijack your request and return a login page that is HTML instead of json