# handleMissingServletRequestParameter method in Spring not returning an empty body

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I have created a global exception handler with the @ControllerAdvice annotation. Please see below for the code snippet. I have defined methods for my custom exceptions and there is a catch all method for other exceptions. An exception like 'MissingServletRequestParameterException' for which there is no
@ExceptionHandler method in the GlobalExceptionHandler class gets handled by the method defined in the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler base class.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends 
ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{

    //Catch all method for other exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> 
      handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
      ErrorResponse er = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
          ex.getMessage(), ex);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(er, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }  

    //Custom exception handlers   
 }
```

The issue is that the exception handler method 'handleMissingServletRequestParameter' in the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class returns only the HTTP status in the header field for the 'MissingServletRequestParameterException' exception. There is no response data i.e. no empty json is being returned back.

I'm using a fetch method in my HTML form and it is waiting for the json response. Here's the code.

```
let data = await response.json();
```

Since there is no json response being returned back from the server, I keep getting the below error message

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () track_grp_hlr_attendance.jsp:1 Uncaught (in     promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at HTMLButtonElement.loadHealerDetails (track_grp_hlr_attendance.jsp:185:35)
```

I fixed the above error by overriding the 'handleMissingServletRequestParameter' method in my global exception handler class.

Here are my questions

1. Why is no empty body being returned back by the handleMissingServletRequestParameter method?
2. There are other exception handler methods defined in the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler base class. If their behavior is the same, then I will have to override each of them and that is not a good solution.

Here's a similar question on stackoverflow. They are solving the issue by checking the content-length in the UI
since the server is not returning an empty body when there is no body.
[Whatwg Fetch fails when json parsing an empty response, how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280029/whatwg-fetch-fails-when-json-parsing-an-empty-response-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: I worked around my issue by overriding the handleExceptionInternal method. All exception handler methods defined in the class ResponseEntityExceptionHandler delegate to the handleExceptionInternal method. This allowed me to remove the override on the handleMissingServletRequestParameter method. It is still not clear why the handleMissingServletRequestParameter method returns no response ( I didn't get an empty json body or an error message in the client response)